# Webservice method with login shows a java error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need help to consume a method of a webservice but I have not been successful.

The method:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Header>
    <LoginInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <Username>[string?]</Username>
        <Password>[string?]</Password>
        <Company>[string?]</Company>
    </LoginInfo>
</Header>
<Body>
    <GetCarsInfoNew xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <DeviceID>[string?]</DeviceID>
    </GetCarsInfoNew>
</Body>
```

This is the code:

```
if(wbs.Autenticacion()){
       System.out.println("Conectado como "+wbs.login.getUsername());
       System.out.println( wbs.port.getCarsInfoNew("xxxxxxx"));
   }
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
```

Comment: Have you taken the advice of the error and checked the server log?

Comment: Tim thanks for the reply.. I dont have access to the server. Only have the url  https://worldfleetlog.com/WebFleetStationServices/Online.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Try SOAP-UI for few Tests, and if it works fine then  try creating same SOAP Message using Java, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I will do as you suggest